# Beautiful Soup - Iterate table rows

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using BeautifulSoup and Python to read a table. The table has numerous rows and numerous `<td>` elements within each row. I am trying to get the text of the first `<td>` element in each row.

```
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

rows = soup.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    row.find('td').text
```

I get the following error...

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

This error is interesting to me because with the following, I get the data I want

```
rows[1].find('td').text.strip()
```

Obviously I only get one row of data and i need to get thousands of rows. I'm sure it's something very simple I'm overlooking but I've spent hours trying to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute error occurs because some rows do not have 'td' element. 
Try this.

```
for row in rows:
    if len(row.find_all('td')) >= 1:
        row.find('td').text
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That did it.